# Different ways of seeing that a $k$-dimensional operator is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

What are some different ways I can see that a $k$-dimensional operator $X$ is normal if and only if $X^\dagger$ is able to be written as a linear combination of $I_{k\times k}$, $X$, $X^2$, $\ldots$, $X^{k - 1}$?

Comment: What is a $k$-dimensional operator?

Comment: Presumably a linear operator on $\mathbb R^k$ or $\mathbb C^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spectral theorem for normal operators, it is enough to show it for diagonal matrices.  If $D$ is a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_i$, we have $D^\dagger = p(D)$ where $p$ is the polynomial of degree $\le k-1$ that interpolates $p(\lambda_i) = \overline{\lambda_i}$,
$i = 1 \ldots k-1$.